# Convert string to integer type in Go?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string returned from `flag.Arg(n)` to an `int`. What is the idiomatic way to do this in Go?

Comment: `strconv.Itoa(i)` (int to ASCII) to set an int to a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546. `strconv.Atoi(s)` (ASCII to int) to set a string to an int. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Answer (score 573, accepted):

For example [`strconv.Atoi`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi).

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    s := "123"

    // string to int
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        // ... handle error
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(s, i)
}
```

Comment: `strconv` can be interpreted as _String Convert_ likewise, is there any meaning (extension) for `Atoi` to make it easier to remember.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala "A" as in A-to-Z for the alphabet which is represented by strings. And then "i" for integer. A to i. That's one way. Another way is to know the origin of "atoi" which is apparently "ASCII to integer": stackoverflow.com/a/2909772/1544473

Comment: It is a shame that in a language created WELL into the era of UNICODE, the best mnemonic the creators of Go could think of were "Alphabet-to-Integer" (which is misleading; decimal digits are not alphabet characters) or "ASCII-to-Integer" (which is obsolete and will someday soon be remanded to the dustbin of history). "Character-to-Integer", "String-to-Integer", or even "Unicode-to-Integer" would have been MUCH better mnemonics, IMO. On reflection it seems like they were just mimicking the C language convention which includes an `atoi()` library function.

Comment: Of course they would mimick the C language convention. This is a good practice, it follows the principle of least surprise.

Comment: ParseInt would be very easy to understand and exists in many languages

Answer (score 145):

#### Converting Simple strings

The easiest way is to use the [`strconv.Atoi()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) function.

Note that there are many other ways. For example [`fmt.Sscan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscan) and [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) which give greater flexibility as you can specify the base and bitsize for example. Also as noted in the documentation of `strconv.Atoi()`:

> Atoi is equivalent to ParseInt(s, 10, 0), converted to type int.

Here's an example using the mentioned functions (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/y4_4HuaWfn)):

```
flag.Parse()
s := flag.Arg(0)

if i, err := strconv.Atoi(s); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("i=%d, type: %T\n", i, i)
}

if i, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("i=%d, type: %T\n", i, i)
}

var i int
if _, err := fmt.Sscan(s, &i); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("i=%d, type: %T\n", i, i)
}
```

Output (if called with argument `"123"`):

```
i=123, type: int
i=123, type: int64
i=123, type: int
```

#### Parsing Custom strings

There is also a handy [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf) which gives even greater flexibility as with the format string you can specify the number format (like width, base etc.) along with additional extra characters in the input `string`.

This is great for parsing custom strings holding a number. For example if your input is provided in a form of `"id:00123"` where you have a prefix `"id:"` and the number is fixed 5 digits, padded with zeros if shorter, this is very easily parsable like this:

```
s := "id:00123"

var i int
if _, err := fmt.Sscanf(s, "id:%5d", &i); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(i) // Outputs 123
}
```

Comment: What does the second argument to `ParseInt` specify?

Comment: @kaushik94 Click on the [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) link and you'll see immediately: `ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int)`. So it's the base: _"ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (2 to 36) "_

Comment: Note that the bitSize argument to strconv.ParseInt() will not convert the string to your choice of type but instead is only there to confine the result to a specific 'bitness'. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925894/parseint-doesnt-convert-to-the-desired-type/55926193

Comment: @viv Yes, that's correct. If a value of type `int` is required and `strconv.ParseInt()` is used, manual type conversion is needed (from `int64` to `int`).

Answer (score 65):

Here are three ways to parse strings into integers, from fastest runtime to slowest:

1. [`strconv.ParseInt(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) fastest
2. [`strconv.Atoi(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) still very fast
3. [`fmt.Sscanf(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf) not terribly fast but most flexible

Here's a benchmark that shows usage and example timing for each function:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"
import "testing"

var num = 123456
var numstr = "123456"

func BenchmarkStrconvParseInt(b *testing.B) {
  num64 := int64(num)
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    x, err := strconv.ParseInt(numstr, 10, 64)
    if x != num64 || err != nil {
      b.Error(err)
    }
  }
}

func BenchmarkAtoi(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    x, err := strconv.Atoi(numstr)
    if x != num || err != nil {
      b.Error(err)
    }
  }
}

func BenchmarkFmtSscan(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    var x int
    n, err := fmt.Sscanf(numstr, "%d", &x)
    if n != 1 || x != num || err != nil {
      b.Error(err)
    }
  }
}
```

You can run it by saving as `atoi_test.go` and running `go test -bench=. atoi_test.go`.

```txt
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkStrconvParseInt-8      100000000           17.1 ns/op
BenchmarkAtoi-8                 100000000           19.4 ns/op
BenchmarkFmtSscan-8               2000000          693   ns/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  5.797s
```

Comment: Clear and helpful answer. I quoted you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Comment: `Atoi is equivalent to ParseInt(s, 10, 0), converted to type int.` https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Atoi

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
import ("strconv")

value := "123"
number,err := strconv.ParseUint(value, 10, 32)
finalIntNum := int(number) //Convert uint64 To int
```

Comment: This code will silently (no error) transform values which are in the `uint32` range but not in the `int` range on platforms where `int` is 32 bits. Example value: `"4234567890"` is converted to `-60399406`. [Go Playground (64 bits)](https://go.dev/play/p/C7znby6qyvF)

Answer (score 2):

If you control the input data, you can use the mini version

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "strconv"
)

func Atoi (s string) int {
    var (
        n uint64
        i int
        v byte
    )   
    for ; i < len(s); i++ {
        d := s[i]
        if '0' <= d && d <= '9' {
            v = d - '0'
        } else if 'a' <= d && d <= 'z' {
            v = d - 'a' + 10
        } else if 'A' <= d && d <= 'Z' {
            v = d - 'A' + 10
        } else {
            n = 0; break        
        }
        n *= uint64(10) 
        n += uint64(v)
    }
    return int(n)
}

func BenchmarkAtoi(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        in := Atoi("9999")
        _ = in
    }   
}

func BenchmarkStrconvAtoi(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        in, _ := strconv.Atoi("9999")
        _ = in
    }   
}
```

the fastest option (write your check if necessary). Result :

```
Path>go test -bench=. atoi_test.go
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkAtoi-2                 100000000               14.6 ns/op
BenchmarkStrconvAtoi-2          30000000                51.2 ns/op
PASS
ok      path     3.293s
```

Comment: What ? Really ? People who wrote "go" made a lot easy. Dont spin your wheel :)

Comment: What about Atoi("-9999")?

Comment: This implementation lacks documentation that would mentions the not handled edge cases (ex: negative decimal integers). And I'm not even mentioning the lack of tests.

Comment: If anybody is tempted to use this despite the comments above be aware that the base is hardcoded to 10 but it decodes letters as if it were an arbitrary base. This will give strange results if you try to decode hex with it.

Comment: A correct benchmark would include all kinds of numbers to see whether there is a difference between decimals and hex. Also hex. is limited to 'F' (not 'Z') and requires 'n *= 16' not 10...