# Idiomatic way to cast a string to any other primitive type

Tags: string, parsing, go, types

I'm trying to create a function that can cast a given string to the given reflect type.

I'm using the [cast](https://github.com/spf13/cast) package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"

    "github.com/spf13/cast"
)

type functions struct{}

func (f functions) Float64(v string) float64 {
    return cast.ToFloat64(v)
}

func toTarget(v string, target reflect.Kind) interface{} {
    n := strings.Title(fmt.Sprintf("%s", target))
    method := reflect.ValueOf(functions{}).MethodByName(n)
    // Call.
    return method.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(v)})[0].Interface()
}

func main() {
    originalValue := "10.0"
    floatingValue := toTarget(originalValue, reflect.Float64)

    fmt.Println(floatingValue)
}
```

In the above example I'm keeping simple (it only works for string -> float64 conversion), but on my code, it will work for all the other primitives as well.

I prefer using this solution over a giant and ugly switch statement, but as a new go developer, I'm not sure if there is a better approach.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no typecasting in Go at all, idiomatic or otherwise. Only type conversion.

Comment: Why not just use `n, err := fmt.Sscan("someString", &variable)`? This will handle most types you'll need. For the rest, you need custom parsing anyway...

Comment: Hey @icza, could you provide a working example of using the `fmt.Sscan`? I'm trying but it keeps returning error `expected integer`.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is valid and provides what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ubaxibuna Using `fmt.Sscan()`, you have to pass the address of a variable, not a `reflect.Kind`, e.g. `var i int; fmt.Sscan("12", &i)`

Comment: Oh, this is good!

Comment: Do you mind to properly answer the question, you deserve points for helping me haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "big switch" statement you want to avoid, that is already written in the standard library. Use the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package to easily parse primitive values from strings, specifically the [`fmt.Sscan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) and [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) functions.

`fmt.Sscan()` requires a string value to parse something out from, and the address of a variable to put the parsed value into. The type of the pointed variable also determines what and how to parse out of the string. `fmt.Sscan()` will return the number of successfully parsed values, and an optional error (if something goes wrong).

A simple example:

```
var i int
if _, err := fmt.Sscan("12", &i); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Println(i)

var f float32
if _, err := fmt.Sscan("12.2", &f); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Println(f)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hQlMhoHI9ZK)):

```
12
12.2
```

Also note that you can parse multiple values in one step with `fmt.Sscan()`, for example:

```
var i int
var f float32

fmt.Println(fmt.Sscan("12 12.2", &i, &f))
fmt.Println(i, f)
```

This will print (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9psywUp_CV7)):

```
2 <nil>
12 12.2
```

The first line contains the return values of `fmt.Sscan()`: tells it parsed 2 values, and returned no error (`nil` error). The second line contains the parsed values of `i` and `f`.

For more options, read: [Convert string to integer type in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278430/convert-string-to-integer-type-in-go/29841190#29841190)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much icza!