# Convert binary value as string to uint32 in Golang

Tags: go, type-conversion

Hello i am trying to convert 00000000000000000000000000001011 to uint32 in golang using

```
var v = "00000000000000000000000000001011"
fmt.Printf("%T\n", v)
c := []byte(v)
u := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(c)
```

However it is not working.

Comment: "Not working" means what? Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: @govind int(0000000000000000000000000000101) should equal uint32(0000000000000000000000000000101) instead got 65

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) for this, as that is to serialize and deserialize the (memory) bytes of different values (e.g. numbers). What you have is the base 2 string representation of the number.

To get its integer value you have to parse it. For that, use [`strconv.ParseUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint):

```
s := "00000000000000000000000000001011"
u, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 2, 32)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(u)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LmxOtO00dP1)):

```
11
```

Note that `strconv.ParseUint()` returns a value of type `uint64`, so if you need `uint32`, you have to manually convert it, e.g.:

```
u32 := uint32(u)
```

There are more options for parsing numbers from strings, for an overview, check [Convert string to integer type in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278430/convert-string-to-integer-type-in-go/29841190#29841190)

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    s := "00000000000000000000000000001011"
    fmt.Println(s)
    u64, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 2, 32)
    u32 := uint32(u64)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(u32)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yiicgWsb7B_M

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000001011
11
```