# ParseInt doesn't convert to the desired type

Tags: go

Here's my code:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
   i, _ := strconv.ParseInt("10", 10, 8)
   fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(i))
}
```

I expect `i` to be 8-bits long (the 3rd argument to `strconv.ParseInt`).  It is int64, however (and the docs state that `strconv.ParseInt` will return int64).

What's the point of ParseInt if it always returns int64 (why not just use Atoi?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note this from the function's doc:

> The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must
>   fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8,
>   int16, int32, and int64. For a bitSize below 0 or above 64 an error is
>   returned.

So it's guaranteed that you can convert your result to a byte with `byte(i)`.

Go doesn't have generics yet, so having a single `ParseInt` that can accept pointers to multiple integer types is difficult. Instead the guarantee is done with the `bitSize` argument

Answer (score 5):

> [Package strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> ```
> import "strconv"
> ```
>
> [func ParseInt](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt)
>
> ```
> func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)
> ```
>
> ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (0, 2 to 36) and bit
>   size (0 to 64) and returns the corresponding value i.
>
> If base == 0, the base is implied by the string's prefix: base 16 for
>   "0x", base 8 for "0", and base 10 otherwise. For bases 1, below 0 or
>   above 36 an error is returned.
>
> The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must
>   fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8,
>   int16, int32, and int64. For a bitSize below 0 or above 64 an error is
>   returned.
>
> The errors that ParseInt returns have concrete type *NumError and
>   include err.Num = s. If s is empty or contains invalid digits, err.Err
>   = ErrSyntax and the returned value is 0; if the value corresponding to s cannot be represented by a signed integer of the given size, err.Err
>   = ErrRange and the returned value is the maximum magnitude integer of the appropriate bitSize and sign.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i64, err := strconv.ParseInt("10", 10, 8)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%[1]d %[1]T\n", i64)
    i8 := int8(i64)
    fmt.Printf("%[1]d %[1]T\n", i8)

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HSHtUnC7qql

Output:

```
10 int64
10 int8
```

---

In Go, we often use functions to hide implementation details.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func ParseInt8(s string, base int) (int8, error) {
    i64, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, base, 8)
    return int8(i64), err
}

func main() {
    i8, err := ParseInt8("10", 10)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%[1]d %[1]T\n", i8)

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HdA3O71U54z

Output:

```
10 int8
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are really asking is what is the point of the 3rd parameter to ParseInt().

It's to save you having to check for overflow manually like this:

```
i, err := strconv.Atoi(intString)
if err != nil || i < -128 || i > 127 {
  // handle error
}
i8 := int8(i)
```